# Airflow S3Hook object has no attribute load_bytes

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

The goal of my operator is to communicate with s3, then write some string data to my s3 bucket.

I saw there is already an s3_hook to be used. I thought maybe this is a better way than using boto3.

The main logic looks like:

```
from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook
hook = S3Hook('test_s3')
log.info(hook.load_bytes('some_data', 'some_key', 'a_bucket'))
```

Then I got some error like

> 'S3Hook' object has no attribute 'load_bytes'

I'm pretty sure that the S3Hook class has that function (see [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/2a8bb0e1b7a15a70519020e69e7369700df5dc37/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.py#L318)).

After this, I switched to use the function `load_string`. However, the airflow throw me an error like:

> 'S3' object has no attribute 'upload_fileobj'

I'm using the airflow with s3 support. Not sure why I the error above. My test_s3 connection is fine since I have tested my `test_s3` connection by using `read_key` to read some texts file from s3 without any issue.

Does anyone else have the similar situation? I'm very confused, where did I miss? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Airflow are you using? The `load_bytes` function has been commited on the 7th of February 2018. Did you look up the function locally on your host or just on the master branch in git? This might also be connected to `load_string`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Currently, I'm using 1.9.0. Guess you are right about the version thing. I just checked the 1.9.0 is released last December. :( So the workaround is to use boto3 until the newest stable version released?

Comment: Why don't you just take the latest version of the s3 hook from the airflow github repository and incorporate it into your airflow installation?